# Can two or more classes send data to the same IntentService?

Tags: android, intentservice

I'm a beginner in Android programming, and I was reading about handling time consuming operations via IntentServices. However, I have this doubt -

Can I have two classes (say A and B) issuing a call to the same class (C) extending the IntentService? Is this possible and/or safe?

If so, how do I help the IntentService differentiate between the two calling classes?

I was thinking of this way:

```
public class DoSomething extends IntentService{
    @Override
        public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            String type = data.getString("TagForClass");
            if(type.equals("TagForClassA")){
                //Do operations for Class A
            }
            else if(type.equals("TagForClassB")){
                //Do operations for Class B
            }
        }
}
```

Will this method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, multiple classes can send intents to the same `IntentService`. Internally, the different calls are queued and processed one by one by the service.

There is something alarming about your use - case. If you need to completely switch the service logic based on the calling class, it would be better to have two distinct services, each one completing a single, well - defined task.